# vim key-biding failing when inside of tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, key-bindings

I use vim as my IDE and tabs inside of it. Instead of changing tabs with gt, gT I mapped Ctrl PageUp and Ctrl PageDown for that, so my `.vimrc` looks like this:

```
nnoremap <C-PageUp> gT
nnoremap <C-PageDown> gt
```

It works just fine outside of tmux... but then, when I open vim from within tmux, and try to change tabs with Ctrl PageUp or Ctrl PageDown it doesn't and it encloses the current word under the cursor in brackets and puts part of it in uppercase... but it won't change the tab in vim. I checked in tmux key-binding if there was anything bound to C-PageUp or C-PageDown but there was nothing. Still I tried to unbind it in .tmux.conf like this, but it won't work:

```
unbind-key C-PageUp
unbind-key C-PageDown
```

Changing tabs in vim with gt and gT works just fine even inside of tmux, but I'm so used to Ctrl PageUp/Down that I would like to keep that.

About the strange behavior...

When in vim within tmux, if my cursor is on the letter `t` of the word `function`, and I press Ctrl PageUp or Ctrl PageDown, the word function is turned into `[funcTION]`. I do have in my .vimrc mappings the following:

```
inoremap [<cr> [<cr>]<c-o><s-o>
inoremap [ []<left>
inoremap <expr> ] strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1, 1) == "]" ? "\<Right>" : "]"
nnoremap [ mmbi[<esc>ea]<esc>`m<right>
vnoremap [ <Esc>`<i[<Esc>`>a<right>]<Esc>
```

They all handle the insertion of closing squared brackets (if you open a square bracket, a closing one is put automatically on the screen). I do have the same for parenthesis, curly brackets, quotes, etc. That 4th one allows me to go in vim normal mode press `[` and it will enclose the word in brackets, that is why I thought this could be influencing the changing of tabs somehow, but I commented all of those lines and it didn't help.

So, my question is, how I identify what is hijacking my key-binding and maybe sending something else to vim? As it only happens when inside tmux, I thought tmux config would be a strong candidate as the hijacker.

What I'm using:
VIM 8.1
tmux 3.0a

EDIT:
Description of the Ctrl PageDown in terminal, with and without tmux, in vim with and without the .vimrc loaded
[image]

Comment: Your keypresses go through several layers before they reach Vim. In this case, the obvious culprit is tmux, which passes something else than a recognisable `Ctrl+PageDown` to Vim. In insert mode, do `<C-v><C-PageDown>`: what does it insert?

Comment: @romainl, in insert mode, <C-v> paste the content of the clipboard, and put it in normal mode, then <C-PageDown> does what was doing before (encloses the word in brackets)

Comment: Do it in `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: I started vim like you said... entered insert mode typed some text: "This is a line to test the ctrl pageup and ctrl pagedown when in tmux" placed my cursor in the letter s of test, entered normal mode, pressed Ctrl PageUp (and Down also) and this is what it became
"This is a line to test the ctrl pAGEUP and ctrl pagedown when in tmux". It kind jumped two words and capitalized all but the first letter of the 3rd word....

Comment: I also removed my .tmux.conf file and tried the same thing with vim -Nu NONE... now "This is a line to test the ctrl pageup and ctrl pagedown when in tmux" became "This is a line to teST THe ctrl pageup and ctrl pagedown when in tmux". If you try that on your side do you get the same result?

Comment: No, I can't do `Ctrl+PageDown` on this machine. None of that is what I suggested, though. My working hypothesis is that tmux is mangling the keycodes before passing them to Vim so what I'm asking you to do is to 1. start Vim without your config (`$ vim -Nu NONE`), 2. enter insert mode (an empty buffer is fine), 3. press `Ctrl+V`, 4. press `Ctrl+PageDown`. it should insert the raw string received by Vim (something that looks like `^[[6~` or some similar string), which should help us diagnose your issue.

Comment: I did what you said, inside tmux (no config), then opened vim with no config (-Nu NONE) entered insert mode, pressed Ctrl V, Ctrol PageDown and it outputed ^[[6;5~

Comment: OK, and outside of tmux?

Comment: the same thing shows up in the terminal...

Comment: I had not realized that Ctrl v was "verbatim". I tried that sequence (ctrl v and ctrl PageDown) in my terminal within and outside of tmux, in vim in tmux and outside with the .vimrc loaded and without. When .vimrc is loaded it outputs ^[[6;5~] instead of ^[[6;5~ (that closing bracket because of my vim key bidings). But I also had a random text and pressed ctrl PageDown on it (no verbatim). When I'm outside of vim, nothing happens (no matter if .vimrc is loaded or not). When I'm inside of tmux, those strange behaviors take place. It's a bit different if .vimrc is loaded or not, but it is weird.

Comment: I edited my post with a screenshot of the output

Comment: I finally found it. Apparently the default terminal in tmux (screen) does not support extended keys like Ctrl PageDown, so you have to change your default terminal. For me it worked with xterm-256color. For that you add this to .tmux.conf `set -g default-terminal xterm-256color`. The discussion about it is [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2186#issuecomment-622614115)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. Apparently the default terminal in tmux (screen) does not support extended keys like Ctrl PageDown, so you have to change your default terminal. For me it worked with xterm-256color. For that you add this to .tmux.conf `set -g default-terminal xterm-256color`. The discussion about it is [here](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/2186#issuecomment-622614115)